# How does Non-Clustered index work when it has a lot of keys with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, non-clustered-index

Suppose that I have a **heap** table with columns (id, name, gender, age)

If I have a NonClustered index in a column "name", what happens if I have like 10 people named "Lucas"? Does the index know which one "Lucas" he is point to? 
If there are so many Lucas' that they are separated in different pages on the B-Tree leafs, does the index still knowing how to find them and which row he has to point for every "Lucas"?

Comment: Really: all your tables **should have** a primary clustered key .... heaps are a steaming pile of data - ***not*** recommended at all!

Comment: @marc_s, having this primary clustered key will prevent unuseful composed non clustered index, right? For example, if I have the keys (ID asc, FirstName asc) in my composed NC Index. Since ID never repeats, FirstName will never be sorted, so it is unuseful. So the best thing here is have the clustered index in ID and a composed NC index with FirstName and LastName for example. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> •If the table is a heap, which means it does not have a clustered index, the row locator is a pointer to the row. The pointer is built from the file identifier (ID), page number, and number of the row on the page. The whole pointer is known as a Row ID (RID).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484(v=sql.105).aspx